# property callbachHandler requires method callbackhandler to be defined-use@synthesize,@dynamic or provide a method implementation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

[image: image for the code part][click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxo1o.png)

please check this image.
when we tried to run the project exception occured due to this warning. Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an older version of Xcode than this code was written in. Upgrade, or do what it says and write a synthesize statement.

Comment: hi thanku jrturton. problem got solved. but we got another warning here like if([SUPApplication ConnectionStatus]==[SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED]){...... ......} we are getting a warning like "comparison between pointer and integer(id and int)" Why like that.Is there any functions to parse both into same datatype

Comment: You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to synthesize it in **iOS version < 6 .**
Add this line after implementation

```
@synthesize callbackHandler;
```

Comment: It's related to the Xcode version, not the iOS version. It's a compiler feature.

Comment: @neelam verma hi thanku neelam. problem got solved. but we got another warning here like
if([SUPApplication ConnectionStatus]==[SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED]){......
......}
we are getting a warning like "comparison between pointer and integer(id and int)" Why like that.Is there any functions to parse both into same datatype